# hiding a panel in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to hide a panel until an item is clicked.

```
xtype: 'processform',
id: 'processCol2',
hidden: true,
columnWidth: 0.5
```

So good so far. The panel is hidden. But how do i re-enable.

I've tried the following

```
 var panel = Ext.getCmp('processCol2');
        panel.hidden = false;
        panel.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: `setVisible` method should do the trick for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post more code? You probably have some other problem. I have made a jsfiddle to show that your implementation should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/sQ58E/

Comment: hey thanks for doing that. you were right the code was correct. I moved the initial hide to the onLaunch function and it worked.